# Google recaptcha V3 timeout in sitecore forms

Tags: sitecore-forms, recaptcha

google reCAPTCHA V3 has timeout 2 mins, there's any way to extend this period?
or how can i handle this short timeout in Sitecore form?

Comment: So if you read this articles, people have done this by adding some logic using javascript code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820652/increase-recaptcha-expiration-time

Comment: @Sara function getReCaptcha(){
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
       ...
     });
 }

 getReCaptcha();  // This is the initial call
 setInterval(function(){getReCaptcha();}, 110000);